# trying to change imageview onPictureTaken from inside a module

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview

i know how to show image if image is taken using this code if all code is in same module(module app)

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
    if (pictureFile == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
// ---- added to display imageView ---- 
        BitmapFactory.Options scalingOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        scalingOptions.inSampleSize = camera.getParameters().getPictureSize().width / imageView.getMeasuredWidth();
        final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, scalingOptions);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        imageView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
// ---- end of changes to display imageView ---- 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

but what if my onPictureTaken is inside a module lets say with the name of magicfilter for example

i know it's not possible to get resource from module app inside sub modules.is there any workaround so i can show my picture inside an imageview after the image is taken?

i did copied all files from that module to my main module app to be able to do this.but some functionality of my app not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem using callback functions that new onPictureSaveListener is a callback listener function so i wrote my code like this

```
mMagicCameraDisplay.onTakePicture(Constants.getOutputMediaFile(), new onPictureSaveListener() {

                @Override
                public void onSaved(String result) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                }
            },null);
```